# Sub with parametres (dictionary with item: array)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can't figure out what's wrong with the code below.
I have created Dictionary contains one key (named "SMTH") and this key contains one items (array with three integers). And now I want it to send this array to Sub procedure, calculate it and return back.

```
Dim SMTH As String
Dim d
Dim Myarray
SMTH = "SMTH"
Myarray = Array(10, 20, 30)
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add SMTH, Myarray

Call countSub(Myarray)             'here is mistake I can't fix

Debug.Print Myarray(0), Myarray(1), Myarray(2)
End Sub

Sub countSub(Arr() As Variant)
For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    Arr(N) = N * 10
Next N
End Sub
```

Type mismatch Error...

I will appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: add `Dim Myarray() As Variant` to the declarations in the first sub.

Comment: It was my typo, sorry. There is still the mistake

Comment: it has to be `Dim Myarray()` not `Dim Myarray`

Comment: Thank you very much! How I can mark your comment as answer?

Comment: The mismatch is between `Myarray` in the call to the sub, and `Arr()` in the Sub argument list. In addition to what @ScottCraner wrote, you could also just change `Arr()` to `Arr`.  It will then work with either `Myarray` or `Myarray()`